# Delete all rows in CSV(Excel) except each nth row

Tags: vba, excel, csv, powerquery

I have a csv dataset file having more than 3 million entries. 
I would like to delete all entries except every 7th entry (keep only every 7th row).
How can i do it using power query OR defining a function while using "Get Data" from text/csv functionality in excel?

Comment: maybe you could add a column which is `=mod(row(),7)` to identify them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Load your source.

Open the Powerquery advanced query editor  > home tab > remove rows > remove alternate rows

Specify pattern as follows:

[image: pattern]

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for posting that. I wasn't aware that PQ could handle data sets that large.